# express dynamic url req.params returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to get a unique id from a dynamic express route from a click on a table row. upon inspecting the row The id is present but clicking on it returns undefined. Here is my code.

PUG (JADE):

```
    .row
  .col-xs-12
    .box
      .box-header
        h3.box-title Staging Campaigns
      .box-body
        table.table.table-bordered.table-hover(name="stagingCampaigns")
          thead
            tr
              th Campaign Name
              th Associated Business
              th Total Budget
          tbody
          mixin stagingCampaigns(campaignID,name,associatedBusiness,budget)
            tr.clickable-row(href='/management/' + campaignID)
              td=name
              td=associatedBusiness
              td=budget

          for campaign in stagingCampaignsArray
            +stagingCampaigns(campaign.id,campaign.name,campaign.associatedBusiness,campaign.budget)
```

NODE:

```
app.get('/management/:campaignID',passportConfig.isAuthenticated, mainController.getCampaign);

exports.getCampaign = (req, res) => {
// create new campaign for brand
console.log(req.params);
if(req.user.accountType === "manager") {
    Campaign.findById(req.params.campaignID, (err, campaign) => {
        if (err)
        {
            //console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render('management/newAd', {
            title: 'Home',
            Campaign:campaign
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure about `campaign.id` parameter when you call `stagingCampaigns` mixin? Maybe you need to use `campaign._id`?

`+stagingCampaigns(campaign._id,campaign.name,campaign.associatedBusiness,campaign.budget)`